# My date columns are different because of time included in one column but not the other. How do I fix this?

Tags: sql, oracle

I've tried to use

```
TO_CHAR(ACTIVE_DT, 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
TO_CHAR(CONTRACT_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

And then a `CASE` statement to find out which dates do not match.

However when I do this it's telling me a lot of them don't match when they should because the contract date field has time in it and the active date does not. But I have used `TO_CHAR` to try and fix it. I'm not sure what else to try.

```
CASE
    WHEN CONTRACT_DATE = ACTIVE_DT 
        THEN 'Correct' 
    WHEN CONTRACT_DATE <> ACTIVE_DT 
        THEN 'Error' 
    ELSE ' ' END 
AS "QC"
```

Comment: The statement is contradictory: "... it's telling me a lot of them don't match when they should because the contract date field has time in it and the active date does not". Date with time is not equal to the date without a time. DBMS cannot lie, please provide reproducible example

Comment: The case expression you've shown isn't using `to_char()` - it would helpful if you showed how you've actually tried to apply it in that expression. Reading between the lines I'm wondering if you've aliased the string versions and think the case will use that; showing a more complete query (or a [mre]) would help too. You can also `trunc()` both dates, but the effect should be the same (unless you have negative dates *8-)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you have to use TRUNC with the appropriate format to truncate your date value, something like:

```
    TRUNC(ACTIVE_DT, 'DD')
```

Comment: Oracle does not have a `DATETIME` data type and a `DATE` data type always has a time component.

Answer (score 0):

If one column has a non-midnight time component and the other column always has a midnight time component then you can match on a 24-hour range (starting from the column at midnight until a day later):

```sql
CASE
WHEN CONTRACT_DATE IS NULL
OR   ACTIVE_DATE IS NULL
THEN ' '
WHEN CONTRACT_DATE >= ACTIVE_DT
AND  CONTRACT_DATE <  ACTIVE_DT + INTERVAL '1' DAY
THEN 'Correct'
ELSE 'Error'
END AS "QC"
```

Alternatively, you can use `TRUNC` (but that may not use the indexes on the columns):

```sql
CASE
WHEN CONTRACT_DATE IS NULL
OR   ACTIVE_DATE IS NULL
THEN ' '
WHEN TRUNC(CONTRACT_DATE) = TRUNC(ACTIVE_DT)
THEN 'Correct'
ELSE 'Error'
END AS "QC"
```